# Multiple values selection in SSRS Report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have **SSRS report** configured which should filter data **by year** provided from client app. I want to let this client app to set multiple years so report filters *by that years with **OR** logic*.

On report side it uses **STRTOSET** function which means it will accept multiple years.

```
Select ( { STRTOSET(@year, CONSTRAINED) })
```

From C# app I set this parameter like this:

```
ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("year", years));
```

My question is - **why this report selects data only for 1 single year, even if I put several** (e.g. 2015, 2016)?

Comment: Need to tick "Allow multiple values" something like this you want?

Comment: There is already a tick on "Allow multiple values", any other ideas?

Comment: show us the function "STRTOSET "

Comment: This is what I have in query:
>   (Select ( { STRTOSET(@year, CONSTRAINED) }) ON COLUMNS 
                      FROM ...
Or what you mean?

Comment: @pedram also it's set to allow multiple values - http://screencast.com/t/VMXBh8ikVkY9

Comment: Hmmm I see, I have to think for the issue will update you

Comment: Please let me know if you have something

Comment: It seems your datasource is an OLAP cube. Share with us the MDX script to populate your parameter.